# How to determine if twins are identical or fraternal if only one is alive?

Tags: human-biology, genetics, twins

I had a twin brother who died at birth. I've missed him all my life, and have been curious to know if we were identical or fraternal.

Is there a test to determine whether we were identical or fraternal?

Comment: This can often be determined by ultrasound during pregnancy, so your parents may know. Are you also male? Is the body still accessible?

Comment: @canadianer I was born in a country where technology such as ultrasound was not available, so my parents don't know. Yes, I am male. No, the body is not available as he died thirty years ago.

Comment: It seems to me that the answer would be no, then.